# Set Tailwind DEFAULT to 500 For All Colors

Tags: tailwind-css

It would seem to me that out of the box, Tailwind base colors should have a DEFAULT set to the mid value 500. For instance 'bg-red' should work with the same value as 'bg-red-500'. Not sure if there is some reason why this is not so.

This would be useful to quickly add bright 'bg' colors to visually check padding and margin, etc. It would also help as a starting place for the color where you throw down the color so you can see if you need to lighten or darken it with a numeric suffix.

I don't want to throw out all the existing colors and start over, so is there a way to set defaults for all the base colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@WillC

A little bit cleaner solution is

```
extend: {
  colors: ({ colors }) => ({
        amber: { ...colors.amber, DEFAULT: colors.amber['500'] },
        blue: { ...colors.blue, DEFAULT: colors.blue['500'] },
        cyan: { ...colors.cyan, DEFAULT: colors.cyan['500'] },
        emerald: { ...colors.emerald, DEFAULT: colors.emerald['500'] },
        fuchsia: { ...colors.fuchsia, DEFAULT: colors.fuchsia['500'] },
        gray: { ...colors.gray, DEFAULT: colors.gray['500'] },
        green: { ...colors.green, DEFAULT: colors.green['500'] },
        indigo: { ...colors.indigo, DEFAULT: colors.indigo['500'] },
        lime: { ...colors.lime, DEFAULT: colors.lime['500'] },
        neutral: { ...colors.neutral, DEFAULT: colors.neutral['500'] },
        orange: { ...colors.orange, DEFAULT: colors.orange['500'] },
        pink: { ...colors.pink, DEFAULT: colors.pink['500'] },
        purple: { ...colors.purple, DEFAULT: colors.purple['500'] },
        red: { ...colors.red, DEFAULT: colors.red['500'] },
        rose: { ...colors.rose, DEFAULT: colors.rose['500'] },
        sky: { ...colors.sky, DEFAULT: colors.sky['500'] },
        slate: { ...colors.slate, DEFAULT: colors.slate['500'] },
        stone: { ...colors.stone, DEFAULT: colors.stone['500'] },
        teal: { ...colors.teal, DEFAULT: colors.teal['500'] },
        violet: { ...colors.violet, DEFAULT: colors.violet['500'] },
        yellow: { ...colors.yellow, DEFAULT: colors.yellow['500'] },
        zinc: { ...colors.zinc, DEFAULT: colors.zinc['500'] },
      }),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is how you can do it. It must be in one of the newer TailwindCss versions (tested in 3.3.3).

In the tailwind.config.cjs (or .js) file, add the following code:

```
  extend: {
  colors: ({ colors }) => ({
    'slate':    { DEFAULT: '#64748b', ...colors.slate},
    'gray':     { DEFAULT: '#6b7280', ...colors.gray},
    'zinc':     { DEFAULT: '#71717a', ...colors.zinc},
    'neutral':  { DEFAULT: '#737373', ...colors.neutral},
    'stone':    { DEFAULT: '#78716c', ...colors.stone},
    'red':      { DEFAULT: '#ef4444', ...colors.red},
    'orange':   { DEFAULT: '#f97316', ...colors.orange},
    'amber':    { DEFAULT: '#f59e0b', ...colors.amber},
    'yellow':   { DEFAULT: '#eab308', ...colors.yellow},
    'lime':     { DEFAULT: '#84cc16', ...colors.lime},
    'green':    { DEFAULT: '#22c55e', ...colors.green},
    'emerald':  { DEFAULT: '#10b981', ...colors.emerald},
    'teal':     { DEFAULT: '#14b8a6', ...colors.teal},
    'cyan':     { DEFAULT: '#06b6d4', ...colors.cyan},
    'sky':      { DEFAULT: '#0ea5e9', ...colors.sky},
    'blue':     { DEFAULT: '#3b82f6', ...colors.blue},
    'indigo':   { DEFAULT: '#6366f1', ...colors.indigo},
    'violet':   { DEFAULT: '#8b5cf6', ...colors.violet},
    'purple':   { DEFAULT: '#a855f7', ...colors.purple},
    'fuchsia':  { DEFAULT: '#ef4444', ...colors.fuchsia},
    'pink':     { DEFAULT: '#ec4899', ...colors.pink},
    'rose':     { DEFAULT: '#f43f5e', ...colors.rose}
  }),   
}
```

Now, bg-red, bg-orange, bg-amber, text-red, text-green etc. should work will show in your intellisense and work in your layouts.